# Proving a simple algebra equation

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

I have to prove the equality:
$$1^3 + 2^3 + · · · + (n − 2)^3 + 2^3 + n^3 = (1 + 2 + · · · + (n − 2) + 2 + n)^2$$

I already know that:
$$1^3+2^3+3^3...+n^3=(1 + 2 + 3...+n)^2$$

How can I derive the second from the first? Perhaps not all through algebraic manipulation, but some logic, because the algebra seems tedious in this equation.

Comment: did you really mean $2^3$ or $(n-1)^3$ In the first equation for the term before $n^3$?

Comment: Have you tried standard induction?

Comment: @MrYouMath Clearly the former, right? The latter is just the same standard identity the OP lists below the question.

Comment: @lulu Induction is a really new concept for me (8th grade), could you explain how I would proceed with induction?

Comment: I'll post something below.

Comment: I posted a standard method for looking at things like this.  What I wrote was fairly terse, so please ask questions if you can't follow.  Glad to explain in greater detail as needed.

Answer (score 1):

Let $A = 1 + 2 + \cdots + (n-1)$.  Then  $A = (n-2)(n-1)/2$ and the identity reads

$$A^2 + 2^3+n^3 = (A+2+n)^2.$$

An $A^2$ cancels and we have

$$2^3+n^3 = 2A(2+n) + (2+n)^2$$

or

$$(2+n)(2^2-2n+n^2) = (n-1)(n-2)(2+n)+(2+n)^2.$$

Cancel the factor of $n+2$.

$$2^2-2n+n^2 = (n-1)(n-2)+(n+2) = n^2 - 3n+ 2 +2+n = n^2-2n +4.$$

Reverse the step and you have a nice proof.

Comment: I don't immediately see how $A^2=1^3+2^3+3^3...(n-2)^3$

Comment: I'm using the identity you say you already know, with $n-2$ in for $n$.

Answer (score 0):

Let us call the left-hand side $L$ and the right-hand side $R$. Then

$$L=1+2^3+\ldots+(n-1)^3+n^3+\left[2^3-(n-1)^3\right]=\left[\dfrac{n(n+1)}{2} \right]^2+\left[2^3-(n-1)^3 \right]$$

The right-hand side is given by:
$$R = \left[1+2+...+(n-2)+(n-1)+n+(2-(n-1))\right]^2=\left[\dfrac{n(n+1)}{2} +(2-(n-1))\right]^2$$

$$=\left[\dfrac{n(n+1)}{2} \right]^2+2\dfrac{n(n+1)}{2} (2-(n-1))+(2-(n-1))^2$$

Now, try to calculate $L-R$ if it is $0$ then you are done. But as many users pointed out the identity is not correct.

Answer (score 0):

Standard induction works.  Easy to verify for $n=2,3$.    We will work with first difference.  The form of induction we'll use is:

Induction:  Given two sequences $\{a_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ and $\{b_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$, if $a_1=b_1$ and, for all $n≥1$ $a_{n+1}-a_n=b_{n+1}-b_n$  then $a_n=b_n$ for all $n\in \mathbb N$.

Given your expression, let the left hand be $L_n$, the right hand $R_n$.

We compute:

$$L_{n+1}-L_n=(n-1)^3+(n+1)^3-n^3=n^3+6n$$

$$R_{n+1}-R_n=(1+2+\cdots+ (n-2)+(n-1)+2+(n+1))^2-(1+2+\cdots +(n-2)+2+n)^2$$

We remark that $$1+\cdots + k=\frac {k(k+1)}2$$ whence $$R_{n+1}-R_n=\big(\frac {n(n+1)}2+3\big)^2-\big(\frac {n(n-1)}2+3\big)^2=n^3+6n$$

and we are done.

Comment: That's awesome! Is that a standard method of proof or is this your own trick?

Comment: @QuestionAble  Ah, I wish I could claim credit for induction, or even for Finite Differences, which  is maybe a better name for this method, but it is many centuries old.